# Library for ILI9806E driver

Tags: embedded, driver, microcontroller, stm32, lcd

I have recently bought IPS LCD module with ILI9806E driver. And I want to use this screen with STM32f44re microcontroller. Can anyone provide me with code written for this driver? I will be glad to see any implementation for any mode (SPI/DPI).

I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that specific display driver or that specific STM32, but I would take a look at the example code ST provides for it's evaluation boards. I'm guessing thats an F4 chip, so I would start with the F4 evaluation examples, they have example code talking to display drivers. Your driver likely won't be far off.

[STM32446e eval](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-eval-boards/stm32446e-eval.html)